# async Controller with async Action doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have async controller with async action. In the action I call WCF service method in SomeMethodOne (it needs 10 seconds to return result) and then I execute some mathematical operations in SomeMethodTwo (it executes about 6 seconds on my computer). As I understand during waiting on result from WCF service method, my computer should execute SomeMethodTwo but it doesn't and all code executes 10 seconds + 6 seconds = 16 seconds. Why?

```
public class TestController : AsyncController
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        string result =  await SomeMethodOne();

        SomeMethodTwo();

        return View();
    }

    private async Task<string> SomeMethodOne() // it needs 10 seconds to return result from WCF service
    {
        using (Service1Client client = new Service1Client())
        {
            return await client.GetDataAsync(5);
        }
    }

    private void SomeMethodTwo() // it executes about 6 seconds on my computer
    {
        double result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            result += Math.Sqrt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The WCF service which I run locally:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }        
}
```

Comment: async does not mean it will not take 16 seconds, it will take 16 seconds

Comment: So where is advantage of using async when we call single WCF method?

Comment: async just make sure here that your thread is freed in to the app pool and when operation completes then it picks again thread from pool and start executing next

Comment: Could you give me example where using async controller and action has more sense?

Comment: your example is right

Comment: `AsyncController` is deprecated. You only need to use `async Task<string>` on a method to make it asynchronous.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos rect: `async Task<ActionResult>` or `async Task<T>` for some `T` derived from `ActionResult`.

Comment: Please see the post I wrote on this topic: http://cpratt.co/async-not-faster/. TL;DR async is not the same as multitasking. All it does is allow the operating thread to be returned to the pool for use by other tasks while it's in a wait-state (idle). The action cannot return until *all* tasks complete, so whether you use async or not it still takes as long as it takes.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're using `await` right away:

```
string result =  await SomeMethodOne();
```

The `await` means that your controller action is going to "asynchronously wait" (await) for the result of `SomeMethodOne` before it continues executing.

If you want to do asynchronous concurrency, then don't `await` right away. Instead, you can start the asynchronous operation going by calling the method and then `await` later:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  Task<string> firstOperation = SomeMethodOne();

  SomeMethodTwo();

  string result = await firstOperation;

  return View();
}
```

Comment: is'nt this statement is synchronous here ? ``Task<string> firstOperation = SomeMethodOne();`` ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Well, you're synchronously *starting* an asynchronous operation.

Comment: how await will behave here ?

Comment: is'nt await line be reached after both methodone and methodtwo are executed completely?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that explains the particulars.

Answer (score 1):

> and **then** I execute [emphasis mine]

Doing one thing and **then** doing another thing will take as long as both of them added together.

Doing two things at the same time **might** be quicker. It might be slower, because of context switching (imagine someone doing lots of "multitasking" and spending more time switching between them than working). It's likely it will be quicker here, if you don't have to get the results from the first action in order to do the second:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    Task<string> task =  SomeMethodOne();

    SomeMethodTwo();

    string result = await task;

    return View();
}
```

Obviously if you needed `result` before you could call `SomeMethodTwo()` then this wouldn't be possible. There is still an advantage on `await`ing `SomeMethodOne()` (which should be called `SomeMethodOneAsync()` if possible to fit with .NET conventions), in that if `GetDataAsync()` is truly async then the thread that was executing this action method can do something else for some other request to your web application, and another thread will pick up on dealing with this one when the I/O operation has returned data. This doesn't help the performance of the single method involved, but does help overall scalability of all the methods being run on the machine for all the web requests.